# Magento 2 - Shippiing Address doesnt have a shipping method

Tags: magento2, quote, shipping-address

im trying to get the quote shipping method by

```
$quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
```

but it always returns null.
then i figured out the shipping_method is not part of the instance getShipping Address is returning. digging in the code, i cant seem to figure out why its not included in the instance. since i didnt see any weird code that would exclude it in the retrival.

[image]

[image]

[image]

NOTE: its not just the shipping method that is missing. the id is also renamed to quote_address_id and i think the instance is smaller than the number of rows present in the DB.

does anyone has an idea why its like this? i just find it weird to retrieved a whole instance of the quote address just to get the shipping method.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that i have the order instance and not the quote instance, so im getting the sales_order_address that really makes sence. my bad for this one.